# How to achieve inheritance in Knockout JS implementation of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have created one component '**measure_parent**' and added one observable variable inside this.

```
this.width = ko.observable(false);
```

Now, I have extended this measure component inside another component '**measure_child**'.

```
return measure_parent.extend({
        initialize: function () {

            this._super();
        },
```

I have attached measure_parent component to one html block

```
<div data-bind="scope:'measure_parent">
```

now, when I am trying to update the value of "width" from the "**measure_parent**" component then binding is working fine. However, when I am updating "**width**" from "**measure_child**" component binding is not working and only **width** variable is getting updated. 
Please note that replacing "**measure_parent**" with "**measure_child**" in data-bind scope is working fine, however as there will be many children components of measure_parent therefore, this approach is not useful in my case.